# Clunky lldb error while printing variables in XCode's debugger console

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, console, lldb

Lately I've got problem to print any kind of variable into XCode's debugger console. It doesn't matter which platform I'm building against. I've tried to reinstall whole XCode, command line tools + cleaned/removed the derived data of swift project I'm working on. None of these steps solved my issue, this error prevent me from using XCode for 100%.

Everytime I'm trying to print something I've got this error in debug console.

```
Printing description of X:
expression produced error: /var/folders/4y/mm1fk7rn5c57ct91syb3ndf40000gn/T/lldb/6651/expr11.swift:1:1: 
error: cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'random type'

$__lldb__DumpForDebugger(Swift.UnsafePointer<Swift.Bool>(bitPattern: 0x104c5ced0).memory)
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<EXPR>:18:7: error: cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'random type'
 if (1==1) {
```

where **random type** can be any type of class/type.

Have anybody came across the same problem lately? Seems like lldb is bit broken when it comes down to print values of swift variables. 
I'm using XCode 7.3.1 (7D1014) with latest update of Mac OS X.

Comment: Can you please file a bug with a repro case attached? I don't think I have seen this issue before

Comment: yes. i will. I guess it has something to do with private interfaces